# What is $\int e^{-\frac{(y-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{\theta})^2}{2}}d\mathbf{\theta}$?

Tags: calculus

$y \in \mathbb{R}, \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are constants, and $\mathbf{\theta} \in [-5,5]\times[-5,5] \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

I'm just not familar with vector integrals, any reference to read?

EDIT: I'm sorry, I missed the square. It was actually part of a Gaussian, $\mathcal{N}(y|\mathbf{x},\mathbf{\theta})$, and I want to integrate w.r.t $\mathbf{\theta}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $x^T\theta = x_1 \theta_1 + x_2 \theta_2$, your integral is separable into multiplicative components involving $\theta_1$ alone and $\theta_2$ alone, so you can just use standard integration by integrating with respect to each variable $\theta_i$ in order, to get the indefinite integral.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. There should be a square in the exponent. Do I need to expand them all, suppose $\mathbf{\theta} \in \mathbb{R}^{100}$?

Answer (score 0):

$x^{T}\theta$ just signifies the inner product between $\theta$ and $x$, so

$$\int_{[-5,5]^{2}} e^{-\frac{y-x^{T}\theta}{2}}\;d\theta=\int_{[-5,5]^{2}} e^{-\frac{y-(x_{1}\theta_{1}+x_{2}\theta_{2})}{2}}\;d\theta=\int_{-5}^{5}e^{\frac{\theta_{1}x_{1}-y}{2}}\;d\theta_{1}\int_{-5}^{5}e^{\frac{\theta_{2}x_{2}-y}{2}}\;d\theta_{2}.$$

Comment: Should it be $e^{-y/2}e^{x_1\theta_1/2}e^{x_2\theta_2/2}$?

Comment: It's the same thing.  You're just taking one more step.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the square.